# How can I find a logically equivalent formula without "implication" or "or"s?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I am trying to finish up my discrete math homework, but I am completely stumped as to how I am supposed to solve this problem. My teacher wants me to find a logically equivalent equation for p v q that does not include exclusive or, implication, or inclusive or (aka she wants me to use only negation and ands). I don't want any answers, for I need to do my homework myself. But please any examples or help would be GREATLY appreciated. I feel as though there is a simple way to do this going right over my head.

Comment: Do you have a table of identities handy? There should be an entry for each of p → q and p ∨ q.

Comment: Yes, I turned it into negation of p implies q, then I Used implication, which turned it back into the original: p v q. I'm not sure where I went wrong or what I should do differently to stop ending up back at the original problem.

Comment: Use a different identity involving p ∨ q. [spoiler](/ "specifically, ¬(p ∨ q)")

Answer (score 0):

Using just NOTs and ANDs, you can create the [NAND gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate). Think of how complements relate ANDs and ORs and try and work it out for yourself before you see a big hint below.

> Use De Morgan's laws to relate NANDs with ORs.

Furthermore, the NAND gate is a [universal gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic), which means that in principle any logic function can be realised with just the NAND gate. Try and see for yourself if you can simulate every other gate with just the NAND one.

If you really want the answer, it's below.

> `p OR q` is equivalent to `(NOT p) NAND (NOT q)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a truth table for p V q:

```
p    q    p V q
T    T    T
T    F    T
F    T    T
F    F    F
```

We need to find an equivalent expression that gives the same final column (T, T, T, F) but using only `not` and `and`.

You can begin enumerating all possible formulas until you find one. The formula should use only p and q and not and and.

```
p    q    p and q
T    T    T
T    F    F
F    T    F
F    F    F
```

First thing we note is that the truth table for and gives three Fs, whereas ours needs three Ts. We can turn Ts to Fs and vice versa using negation, so maybe we guess that.

```
p    q    not(p and q)
T    T    F
T    F    T
F    T    T
F    F    T
```

This seems close, except we need T, T, T, F and we have F, T, T, T. We might notice that this pattern is totally backwards, and since the variables are ordered by truth value, we might guess that swapping truth values would work. To swap truth values, we use negation again:

```
p    q    not(not p and not q)
T    T    T
T    F    T
F    T    T
F    F    F
```

We found what we wanted. Now, I knew what the answer would be, but even if I hadn't, we would have eventually reached here by just listing out reasonable logical formulas in order. We knew:

1. Both symbols had to appear
2. Only "and" could allow both symbols to appear
3. The only other symbol allowed was not
4. not not x = x; so we don't need to duplicate

The formulas we could have blindly started writing down truth tables for is:

- p and q
- (not p) and q
- p and (not q)
- not(p and q)
- not(p) and not(q)
- not(not(p) and q)
- not(p and (not q))
- not((not p) and (not q))

At which point we could have found the answer with no insights other than the four points above.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about what the sentence `p v q` means.

p and q are, of course, two propositions - simple sentences that are true or false.

The sentence `p v q` is just saying 'p is true and/or q is true'. Basically, `p v q` is true when at least one of the two propositions are true.

So ask yourself the opposite: when would that sentence be false? Why, when neither of them are true! How would we express this? `not p and not q`

That amounts to saying that `not (p or q)` and `not p and not q` are equivalent sentences.

Which implies that `not not (p or q)` and `not(not p and not q)` are equivalent.

Now, by the double negation law, we know that two negations cancel out.

So we have `p or q` and `not(not p and not q)` are equivalent sentences.

And that is the answer you were looking for.